# Magento 2 : One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running

Tags: magento2, admin, indexing

I find error admin "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running"

I've run command Re-Index `php bin / magento indexer: reindex` but appeared issue another `Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in / home / qyivmqoz / public_html / magento2 / vendor / Magento / framework / Locale / Bund le / DataBundle php on line 64`

I use PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6

Is there a solution for my problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it more readable and clear what you're actually asking?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the issue

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
>   running

Just run the query:

`UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid'`

And the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found

is due to missing `intl` extension.

Make sure if you have PHP `intl` extension installed.
You can simply check either from `phpinfo()` or from CLI as

`php -m | grep intl`